# .Net PostgreSQL NpgsqlBatch. Apply SET TIME ZONE to select query

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

How to apply `SET TIME ZONE` to NpgsqlCommand?

Attempt 1. `SET TIME ZONE` in CommandText, separated from select with `;`

```cs
using var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SET TIME ZONE '+02:00'; select \"t0\".\"start_time\" from \"task\".\"tasks\" \"t0\" where \"t0\".\"number\" = 217";
await connection.OpenAsync();
using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

Attempt 2. Use `NpgsqlBatch`

```cs
await connection.OpenAsync();

using var batch = new NpgsqlBatch(connection);
batch.BatchCommands.Add(new NpgsqlBatchCommand("SET TIME ZONE '+02:00'"));
batch.BatchCommands.Add(new NpgsqlBatchCommand("select \"t0\".\"start_time\" from \"task\".\"tasks\" \"t0\" where \"t0\".\"number\" = 217"));
await batch.PrepareAsync();

using var reader = await batch.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

`start_time` column is type of `timestamptz`

In neither attempt did `SET TIME ZONE` work. As I understand it: 1 attempt did not work because `npgsql` split command text by semicolon `;` into batches. So `SET TIME ZONE` is in individual batch and does not apply to `select`.

More about batches in `npgsql`
https://www.infoq.com/news/2022/06/Database-Command-Batching/

When I run query in PgAdmin, `SET TIME ZONE` works - I got different result

```sql
SET TIME ZONE '+02:00';
select 
    "t0"."start_time"
from "task"."tasks" "t0"
where "t0"."number" = 217
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `SET TIME ZONE` in the first place? The [NpgSQL type docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html#net-types-and-postgresql-types) say that if `start_time` is a `timestamp with time zone` you'll get back a DateTime at UTC, with DateTimeKind set to `UTC`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added field type to question

Comment: You haven't explained why you use `SET TIME ZONE`. The docs I linked to explain you'll get back a UTC DateTime, no matter what the local timezone is. PostgreSQL itself [stores timsetamptz as a UTC timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT-TIME-STAMPS) without the offset or timezone name and converts it to local time when queried.

Comment: The `DateTime` value you get back is accurate, as it's clearly marked UTC. Why can't you use it as is? Does the application format it as if it was a local time perhaps? In that case you can convert it to the application's local time with `DateTime.ToLocalTime()`. That's a *lot* safer than hard-coding an offset that will change twice a year. You can use `AT TIME ZONE` with a timezone *name*, eg `AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'` to ensure you get a valid local time no matter the DST rules

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the comments. Yes, there are other options without `SET TIME ZONE`. Maybe I'll have to use one.

Is it possible to aplly `SET TOME ZONE` to `SELECT` query in .NET ?

Comment: There are other ways to convert the stored UTC timestamp to Local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code above does set the time zone successfully; if you execute `SHOW TIME ZONE` afterwards you should get back the value that you set.

However, Npgsql is - very much by design - not sensitive to whatever the time zone is set to. Technically, in PostgreSQL TIME ZONE only has an effect when a `timestamp with time zone` is converted to a textual representation, to a `timestamp without time zone`, etc. However, Npgsql does not convert the timestamp to text; it retrieves it from PostgreSQL in its binary encoding, which is simply the UTC timestamp (which is also what is stored on disk).

Therefore, changing TIME ZONE simply does not affect what you get from Npgsql.

Answer (score 0):

`SET TIME ZONE` has no effect with good reason.NpgSQL returns `timestamp with time zone` as a DateTime value whose `Kind` is DateTimeKind.UTC. This is explained in the [type mapping docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html#net-types-and-postgresql-types). PostgreSQL itself stores `timestamp with timezone` as a UTC value, without the original offset or timezone name. From [the PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT-TIME-STAMPS):

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.

> When a timestamp with time zone value is output, it is always converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as local time in that zone. To see the time in another time zone, either change timezone or use the AT TIME ZONE construct

The value returned by NpgSQL is accurate - a UTC DateTime. This shouldn't be a problem if the application treats this as a UTC time. Unfortunately, functions like `ToString` *ignore* the `Kind` property. In this case a good choice would be to convert the value to a local date in C# with [DateTime.ToLocalTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=net-7.0), eg :

```
while(reader.Read())
{
   ...
   var date=reader.GetDateTime(3).ToLocalTime();
   ...
}
```

Another option is to convert the value to a `DateTimeOffset`, ensuring UTC and local are never confused:

```
var date=new DateTimeOffset(reader.GetDateTime(3));
```

Another option is to use `AT TIME ZONE` to have PostgreSQL convert the time to a specific timezone. Don't use the offset though, as this will change based on DST rules. It's far safer to use the IANA timezone name, eg:

```
var sql="""
select "start_time" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' 
from "task"."tasks" "t0"
where "t0"."number" = 217
""";

cmd.CommandText=sql;
```